# JScript in Microsoft Orchestrator

Tags: javascript, powershell

I've tried to run JScript in system center orchestrator,  instead of powershell however I've run into some problems:

Here's little the code snippet:

```
var location = '{location from "InitializeData"}';
```

However when I run this script Im getting error,

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Im getting this error when I'm trying to get value of the location through `Published data`.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `var location = {location from "InitializeData"}` (no quotes)

also, afair, you should return something from the powershell step, else it will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however when I'm not using quotes im getting an error that "Variable has not been declared". Do you know how I can just return this location here ? I'm new to orchestrator.

Comment: ah wait,  i just figured you said javascript, are you sure thats even possible? how does that work, there supposed to be some kind of runner? I never tried JS in orchestrator

Comment: I can choose JScript in orchestrator activity, so I think yes, it should be possible.

Comment: wow, i never knew. blown = mind, well but looking at my notes about orca, i see that i had `$servicedeployment = Get-SCServiceConfiguration -Name {Service Name from "Initialize Data"}` like so, but that's powershell